# Memcached update only single element of the value array

Tags: memcached

Is it possible to update only one element in the value array when i am using `Memcached`? Lets say i set a key `boots` and the value of this key is :

```
(key)boots =>
(value)[
   [
      'id' => 1,
      'type' => 'winter boots'
   ],
   [
      'id' => 2,
      'type' => 'summer boots'
   ],
   [
      'id' => 3,
      'type' => 'spring boots'
   ]   
]
```

And if i update (lets say 'summer boots' become 'all season boots') how should i retrive the new data only for the updated product from the `MySQL` database table and refresh only that particular product and not retriving all the products data and updating the whole value (i mean this is the way `memcached` works right?) ? Should i use some kind of sorting algorithms like `merge sort`,`quicksort` or i have to use another caching system ? I hope i explain what i am looking for right. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think that is possible is to get the whole object that is stored in memcache and then change it and store it back.

There is also a second way:
Look into how frequently you update the element that you store in memcache and what is the size of the element that you store.

If it is very large array then it would not make any sense to store the whole object in memcache. 
Then it would e better to store each entry as a different key which would look something like this:

(key)boots_1 => (value)winter boots

(key)boots_2 => (value)summer boots

(key)boots_3 => (value)spring boots

This would allow you to independently change keys and you could do a multiget from memcache to get all the keys.